# Using Font-Awesome with Sass

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

I want to set up Font-Awesome with Sass and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.I'm getting some bordered squares instead of the icons.Here's what I did:

1. Downloaded font-awesome directory.
2. Copied `font-awesome.css` in my css folder.
3. Copied font files in my fonts folder.
4. Copied sass _partials and `font-awesome.scss` in my sass folder.
5. Imported `font-awesome.scss` in my main.sass file using: `@import "font-awesome.scss"`
6. Compiled `main.scss` and `font-awesome.scss`

I didn't change `$fa-font-path` inside `_variables.css` partial because the default path`(../fonts)` seems correct.Here's my project structure:

```
root
    css
       font-awesome.css
    fonts
       *(fontawesome font files)*
    sass
       font-awesome.scss
       main.sass
       *(_partials)*    
    js
       main.js
```

Comment: Seeing squares instead of icons means that the font-files aren't found. Are you sure the path is correct? Have you checked if there's an error in your console?